# upload gzip file in api request express server nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, gzip, node-streams

I want to upload 'content-encoding:gzip' gzip file using express server in nodejs. I want to know what is the npm module I can use for better performance to receive and uncompress gzip file in request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two methods to handle this. first

```
npm i compression --save
```

then in your server.js

```
const compression = require("compression");
server.use(compression());//make sure you use this  on top of the middlewares
```

Express middleware will compress your files at the point of request.
Another solution is to let Webpack compress your files and create .gz versions of your uncompressed files.

```
npm i --save compression-webpack-plugin
```

this package uses "gzip" algorithm by default

in your webpack.config.js for production

```
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

plugins: [
      new CompressionPlugin(),
    ]
```

this will compress your assets files except jpeg images. because jpeg is already a compressed file type. now you need to tell express how to handle compressed files.
for this install

```
  npm i express-static-gzip
```

in your server.js

```
 const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
    server.use(expressStaticGzip("dist"));//make sure you use this middleware first.
```

Webpack compression will compress your files one-time - during your build run. Those compressed versions are then saved to disk